# How can I backup my Incredimail?

Tags: backup, email

One of the family computers has Incredimail as its default mail client.  It has years of mails backed up on it.  Unfortunately, the computer has reached the point where it needs to be reinstalled.

What's the best way to backup and restore the Incredimail data files?

Answer (score 1):

**[How to Back Up IncrediMail Emails, Contacts, and other Data](http://email.about.com/od/incredimailtips/qt/How_to_Back_Up_IncrediMail_Emails_Contacts_and_other_Data.htm)**

and before you wipe the computer, you may want to create a drive image (e.g. with [DIXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)) so you still have the access to ALL files, in case you need them.

Answer (score 0):

There are some commercial tools out there and there is 
https://code.google.com/p/incredimail-converter-reynardware/ for free.
However, I was unable to run it through to the end of 2GB worth of mails (including attachments).
So I rolled my own command line tool:
https://github.com/revaultch/incredimail-converter-cmdline

Tested on a Mac quad core with SSD, it takes roughly 10 seconds for 1734 messages resulting in 2.1GB of EML-files.

Feedback welcome:
https://github.com/revaultch/incredimail-converter-cmdline/issues